# after upgrading to meteor 0.9.1 i keep getting "Warning: Blaze.insert has been deprecated."

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Hi I just upgraded my meteor app to 0.9.1.1 and I keep getting these 2 warnings in my console

```
W20140910-18:37:07.781(3) (blaze.js:67) Warning: Blaze.render without a parent element is deprecated. You must specify where to insert the rendered content. logging.js:65
W20140910-18:37:07.787(3) (blaze.js:67) Warning: Blaze.insert has been deprecated.  Specify where to insert the rendered content in the call to Blaze.render. logging.js:65
```

I have no idea from where the error occurs, or why it happens.

Any idea of what I might be missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code where `Blaze.insert` and `Blaze.render` are being called. The warnings are crystal clear, the Blaze API changed a bit and you need to account for these changes. What I suspect though is that you may be depending on packages who are using the Blaze API, so warnings aren't spawned directly from your own code.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually the iron:router package. Is this something I should worry about ?

Comment: When possible, always try to update your environment to the latest versions, that would be METEOR@0.9.1.1 and iron:router@0.9.3 as we are speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blaze API changed in meteor 0.9+ 
If you are using

```
 UI.insert(UI.render(Template.foo), document.body)
 UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.foo, {bar: "baz"}), document.body)
```

You need to update `UI.insert()` **&** `UI.insert(UI.renderWithData())`

to the new Blaze API:

```
Blaze.render(templateOrView, parentNode, [nextNode], [parentView])
Blaze.renderWithData(templateOrView, data, parentNode, [nextNode], [parentView])
```

Check updates: http://docs-0.9.1.meteor.com/#blaze_render