# Update parent template's dynamic template include from child template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm pretty new to Meteor and need some help.

I have an outer parent template that contains a side slide menu. That side slide menu is using the new Blaze Dynamic Template include.

```
<div id="parentTemplate">

   {{>yield}}

   <div class="right-slide-menu">

      {{> UI.dynamic template=rightSideMenu}}

   </div>

</div>
```

So since I'm using Iron-router, when a new child template gets injected into "yield" from iron-router the right side menu needs to change depending on what "page" it is on now.
I am trying to figure out how to update the parent Dynamic template slide menu from the child template. I can do this pretty easily with Angular...but I can't seem to figure this one out using Meteor.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Note that as of 0.9.4, UI.dynamic has been replaced with [`{{> Template.dynamic }}`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_dynamic).

Comment: What about using Iron Router [regions](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-into-regions-with-javascript)?

Comment: Thanks Sacha, I've never heard of them before. I'll look into it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I actually got this to work. I found the solution on this blog here:

http://empire5.com/development/meteor-rendering-a-handlebars-template-with-dynamically-loaded-data/

UI.render and UI.insert are deprecated (although it still works for now) so I adapted his instructions to the new way of doing this:

[after upgrading to meteor 0.9.1 i keep getting "Warning: Blaze.insert has been deprecated."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769675/after-upgrading-to-meteor-0-9-1-i-keep-getting-warning-blaze-insert-has-been-d)

So the final code looks like this:

```
<div id="parentTemplate">

   {{>yield}}

   <div class="right-slide-menu">

      <div class="sideMenu">

        <!-- side menu template gets injected here -->

      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Inside my child template manager I have this:

```
Template.dashboard.events({

    'click #showSideMenuBtn' : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // pass in the name of the template you want to inject and 
        // also the parent container you want to inject it into
        Blaze.render(Template.addManagerForm, $('.sideMenu')[0]);

    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) variable?

```
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  // assuming two templates...
  whichMenu: function () {
    return Session.get('whichMenu') ? 'menuTemplate1' : 'menuTemplate2'
    // or just Session.get('menuTemplate'), and you store the template name there
  }
});
```

Then

```
<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=whichMenu}}
</template>
```

You can get the current "page" with `Router.current()`, and `Session.set('menuTemplate')` accordingly.

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the reply. I tried using Session like you suggested as far as setting it from the child template and unfortunately it did not work. I even tried wrapping the call to Session.get in Tracker.autorun and it still won't update. :-/